# How to INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES(value) WHERE column2 = value

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

I am working on a Time Clock program but I am having trouble with this query:

```
INSERT INTO users(time_in) VALUES($2) WHERE username = $1
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
time_json VARCHAR,
time_in VARCHAR
);
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
error: syntax error at or near "time_in"
at Connection.parseE (\...\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:606:11)      
at Connection.parseMessage (\...\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:403:19)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (\...\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:123:22)  
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
name: 'error',
length: 95, 
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42601', 
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: '8',
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'scan.l',
line: '1134',
routine: 'scanner_yyerror'}
```

Code for the function I am working on:

```
function postTimeIn(user, callback) {

const timeIn = getTime();
params = [user, timeIn];

const sql = 'INSERT INTO users(time_in) VALUES($2) WHERE username = $1';

pool.query(sql, params, function (err, result) { ...
```

Comment: That's not a valid syntax in Postgres: `INSERT INTO ... WHERE` -- are you trying to do an upsert?  A `WHERE` clause is valid for upsert, but that's not how you'd do it

Comment: In `insert query`, why do you need `where` ?

Comment: I figured it wasn't valid syntax but I am not sure how else to insert a value into the time_in column for a given user

Comment: Do you, by any chance , want to `UPDATE` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause would make sense with an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE users
SET    time_in = $2
WHERE  username = $1;
```

Is that what you really want?

`username` should be defined `UNIQUE` for this - and probably in any case.

`time_json` should probably be type `json` or `jsonb`. `time_in` should probably be `timestamptz`.

An `INSERT` would not make any sense (apart from the invalid syntax), as you would have to fill in all `NOT NULL` columns without column default at the same time:

```
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: That makes sense, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to insert a record with a where condition. You can only use a where condition only as a filter when you are inserting values selected from another table
like.
`INSERT INTO table(column1,column2,...)
SELECT column1,column2,...
FROM another_table
WHERE condition;`

In your instant you should do an update as suggested above because you are changing the attribute value of an already existing record.